# How to import a file with a part of the filename being the folder name

Tags: import, data

Consider a bunch of folders `.../run_i`, where i = 1, 2,..., and ... means some pre-path (say, `folderpath = "Events/run_i"`). In each of the folders, among a bunch of files, there is a file `run_i_dat.txt`, where `i` corresponds to the folder name.

How, by specifying `folderpath`, to import the file? The problem is that I do not know how to split the folder name and extract `run_i` from the folder path, and then merge `run_i` and `_dat.txt` to import the file.

**Edit**

Okay, the first problem has been solved, there is `FileNameTake`.

**Edit 2**

The second problem has also been solved: `StringJoin`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you have this list of directories:

```
folderpaths = 
  {"Events/run_1", "Events/run_2", "Events/run_3", "Events/run_4", "Actions/run_1", "Actions/run_2"}
```

We can split up the paths like this:

```
dirPathLists = FileNameSplit /@ folderpaths
(* {{Events,run_1},{Events,run_2},{<<1>>},<<1>>,{Actions,run_1},{Actions,run_2}} *)
```

Now, it sounds like there is a very deterministic pattern for the filename based on the file's immediate parent directory. So, let's build a function that does that work:

```
nameFromDirectory[dir_String] := dir <> "_dat.txt";
nameFromDirectory["run_1"]
(* "run_1_dat.txt" *)
```

We can apply our function to the last element of each path, and append it to the path:

```
fullPathLists = Append[#, nameFromDirectory[#[[-1]]]] & /@ dirPathLists
(* {{Events,run_1,run_1_dat.txt},<<4>>,{Actions,run_2,run_2_dat.txt}} *)
```

You can now assemble them into path strings:

```
FileNameJoin /@ fullPathLists
(* {Events/run_1/run_1_dat.txt,<<4>>,Actions/run_2/run_2_dat.txt} *)
```

At this point, you can import each file.